# Generic type constraint for significant classes

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to define generic constraint for multiple classes that doesn't share a base class/interface?

For ex.

```
class A
{
}

class B
{
}

class C
{
    void Test<T>(T someObj)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to pass either class A or B to Test method, nothing else.

I know that I can put a where statement with the base class/interface of A or B but I can't specify base interface/class for the related classes in my situation.

Comment: No, if you only support two type with no common interface then your method isn't generic, use overloading instead.

Comment: Agree, just use method overloading.

Comment: Short answer is no you can't, there is no "or" construct in generic type constraints so you can't say where T : A or T : B.

Comment: Why you cannot specify base interfaces? You can add a fictive interface name just to be able to use the where statement, the interface itself can be empty.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Aforementioned classes are auto-generated classes from an entity model. If I were to specify a base class to either of them, I need to reimplement that base class everytime I update the model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, and it doesn't make sense to do so. It isn't a generic any more. If class `A` and `B` share properties, methods, etc, they should share the same interface or base class. If not, they are not 'the same' and can't be treated as such.

Guess what would happen if you changed the method signature in one of the two classes. Suddenly that method isn't 'shared' any more. The compiler doesn't try to determine what methods and properties can be considered shared, instead it doesn't support the feature you request.

An option would be to use two methods (one overload of every type) which introduces repeating code, which is bad of course. It would be better to use an `interface`, or if it is really out of you hands `dynamic`, although I try to minimize the use of it.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible in compile time.

If it would be, how would you use the generic parameter type `T`? Would it behave like `A` or like `B`?

Consider the following:

```
class A
{
    public void MethodInA();
}

class B
{
     public void MethodInB();
}

class C
{
    // pseudocode here!
    void Test<T>(T someObj) where T : A or B
    {
        // how it would behave if T is B?
        someObj.MethodInA();
        // how it would behave if T is A?
        someObj.MethodInB();
    }
}
```

Instead extract some base class or interface, that will be common for both `A` and `B` classes and use it in your generic method constraint.

Answer (score 1):

If there's nothing shared, then:

```
void Test(A obj) {}
void Test(B obj) {}
```

is the only real way to do it. You *could* make the generic method private, and the overloads public, and just call the private method from the overloads, as in:

```
private void TestImplementation<T>(T object) { ... }
public void Test(A obj) { this.TestImplementation(obj); }
public void Test(B obj) { this.TestImplementation(obj); }
```